# How to get Visual Studio JavaScript Intellisense to recognize my own classes when passed between functions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

For the most part, once you know the ins-and-outs, Intellisense for JavaScript in VS 2010 works pretty well. However. Consider the following example:

```
   function ClassA(someClassB) {
       ///<summary>My A Class</summary>
       ///<param type="ClassB" name="someClassB">An instance of my B Class</param>
       someClassB.method1(); //Intellisense doesn't work
       this.method2 = function() {
            ///<summary...
       };
   }

   function ClassB(someClassA) {
       ///<summary>My A Class</summary>
       ///<param type="ClassA" name="someClassA">An instance of my A Class</param>
       someClassA.method2(); //Intellisense doesn't work
       this.method1 = function() {
            ///<summary...
       };
   }
```

In neither case does Intellisense suggest the available methods, from either class. I have references, and I created vsdocs--and in all other cases, Intellisense works just fine. But. If I insert this (very hackadelic) `if(false)` snippet into each class:

```
function ClassA(someClassB) {
    ...
    if(false) {
        someClassB = new ClassB();
    }
    ...
    someClassB.method1(); //Intellisense now works
}
```

So it's clear that Intellisense is able to read my XML documentation and service my classes; but it doesn't seem to read the type which I'm defining in the `<param>` node. This does work for jQuery, which I note coming into relevant functions using `<param type="jQuery" name="$"></param>`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is working for jQuery? try naming your jQuery parameter jQ... I doubt you'll get the same intellisense with jQ(

From what I've seen, VS does not do anything with the parameter datatypes except display member info when you are calling the functions.  The intellisense with jQuery is because it is defined as $ already.

Comment: You're right. I get Intellisense without using a <param> for jQuery ($). It's clear that the param type is not utilized. Is there a way to nudge VS in the right direction?

Comment: Other than your shifty `if(false)` I don't think I've figured out a way yet...  You might be able to do `someClassB = someClassB || new ClassB();` Which is slightly cleaner than the `if(false)`.  Though also you need to look closer at the side-effects of this instantiation (if any).  You could also use `ClassB.prototype.method1.call(...)` or `.apply(...)` if you are using the method in prototype and you can salvage some intellisense from that...

Comment: I agree that your someClassB = someClassB || new ClassB(); approach is cleaner; but it's still an eyesore at the least and a maintenance booby trap at the worst (as is my shifty hack). In the cases where I can instance the class without a constructor, I've simply added an if (isNullOrEmpty(someClassB)) { someClassB = new ClassB(); }. This is at least legitimate and clear, but it doesn't help in the many cases where constructors are required.

Comment: I sure wish VS JS intellisense could do this. If there's a solution, I'd love to know what it is. It sucks if we have no choice between changing code to fit intellisense or going without.